# What is a good fan speed algorithm?

Tags: performance

My fan has 24 speedsteps. Thermal shutdown is 105°C it think. Idle temperature is about 75°C. Is a good algorithm to take a temperature lower bound and a temperature higher bound and divide it by n speedsteps?

EDIT: ATM I use 2 loops and up_threshold of 85°C but that was before I know about 24 speedsteps:

```
error |= ec_read(EC_RTMP, &ec_rtmp);
if ( ( ec_rtmp < FAN_UPTHRESHOLD_TEMP && sloop < 0 ) ||
    ( ec_rtmp < FAN_UPTHRESHOLD_TEMP && sloop == FAN_LOOP ) ||
         ( ec_rtmp < FAN_UPTHRESHOLD_TEMP && speed_switch == 1 )    
    )
{
    speed_switch = 1;
    sloop = FAN_LOOP;                           // 20 * 10 sec
    printk("Temp %dC: disabling fan\n", ec_rtmp);
    set_fan_disabled();
    queue_delayed_work( my_workqueue, &work_object, FAN_JIFFIES_MS*HZ );
} else 
{
    speed_switch = 0;
    printk("Temp %dC: enable fan\n", ec_rtmp);
    set_fan_enable();
    queue_delayed_work( my_workqueue, &work_object, 2*FAN_JIFFIES_MS*HZ );
}
```

EDIT: I've found a good source code: http://code.google.com/p/eeepc-fancontrol/wiki/Formular

Comment: *Doesn't sound like a programming question.*

Comment: I've googled there is 2 strategy. 1 is a table-based approach.

Comment: @Nick, I don't agree. OSes are also programs. Asking how to change kernel IS a programming question.

Comment: it depends on what is meant by "what is a good algorithm"... the OP hasn't provided a description of what the algorithm actually needs to do. If the OP is asking "what's the best algorithm to keep my computer happy" then they are asking about the best way to maintain the state of their hardware. if they are asking "what's the best algorithm to implement this end result" (where they then describe the end result of the wanted algorithm) then they are asking a programming question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to consider many factors, firstly you don't want the fan constantly bouncing between two different steps, so a common trick is to only change the fan speed on a time based interval or if it crosses two boundaries higher than when the fan speed last changed.

If your goal is to just stop the laptop from getting any hotter, then using a table of speed steps will be mostly suitable, but it won't be ideal, and might have the laptop getting hotter than it other wise needs to be. Imagine if your fan was always one or two settings slower for the current heat output than it needed to be. What I'm getting at is **fan speed should be related to change in temperature NOT directly related to temperature**, but at the same time don't totally reject temperature, you need also to have a threshold table that says fan must be at least speed X when temperature is over Y.

So design your system based on temperature gain / loss (delta) over a time interval rather than temperature at a given point in time.

Also one other thing to consider is that fans generally don't increase linearly in cooling with RPM, they usually follow a bell curve for efficiency where they ramp up towards peak cooling efficiency (vs RPM) and then as you go higher RPM they won't be as efficient in cooling down. You might very well find that the last 10% fan RPM increases by several DB but might not do much more at all in the way of removing heat.

I would suggest using a minimum fan speed that is just below where you would generally like the fan running at in normal quiet conditions. Rather than just going 10%, 20%, 30%.. 90%, 100% fan RPM, I would say start at 40% (or what feels best for you) and then at this speed see what your new idle temperature is, then use that as your base point for increasing the remainder of the fan speed.

There is no perfect generic solution for this problem you will get something that could always be improved upon based on the heat output compared to your current interpretation of what noise is costly. As such you should look to implement different sets of settings for `quiet`, `office` or `gaming` profiles (based on roughly what your importance and system load will be for a given situation). Much like cars which have a `sports mode`, or `off road` setting.